# How to adjust colors in angular material default themes

Tags: angularjs, angular-material

My users are complaining that the change in color for md-buttons on focus is too subtle.

What is the right way to make an adjustment to this for the default color palettes?

Append:  I am looking on how to adjust the button styling when the button has focus, not looking for how to create my own theme.

Also, I am using Angular-Material 1, NOT 2

Comment: Have you read e.g. https://github.com/angular/material2/blob/master/docs/theming.md?

Comment: Yes I have, and that does NOT answer my question, so don't be so quick to give me a negative score.

Comment: Oh sorry; have you read the equivalent docs for AM1? What have you tried, and what's the problem with it? Have you tried just adding your own CSS?

Comment: I cannot find where the css is generated.  I have examined the DOM, and can see that the color is adjusted, but do not know if it is based on a predefined hue, or if the formula is used to alter from the default.  I assume its one of those, since it has to work for all the default palletes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK, for anyone else looking for this, I found the answer in angular-material.modules.closure.button and angular-material.modules.js.button

```
.md-button.md-THEME_NAME-theme.md-primary.md-fab:not([disabled]):hover {
  background-color: '{{primary-600}}'; }
.md-button.md-THEME_NAME-theme.md-primary.md-raised:not([disabled]).md-focused, .md-button.md-THEME_NAME-theme.md-primary.md-fab:not([disabled]).md-focused {
  background-color: '{{primary-600}}'; }
```

This tells me what I needed, which is that focused buttons get primary-600.

NOW I can customized the theme palletes as recommended in the first comment